# Does PHP 5.5 work with MongoDB driver?

Tags: php, mongodb

I've just installed PHP 5.5 and I am no longer able to use MongoClient and I'm getting frustrated trying to figure out why.

This doesn't work:

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://workplz.com");
```

My nginx error log shows:

> 2013/07/05 10:40:16 [error] 4163#0: *698 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /blah/test.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: blah, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/freecookies.sock:", host: "blah"

I do have `extension=mongo.so` in my php.ini.

When I do phpinfo() it shows under **Mongo** `Version 1.4.1`

Extra info:

- PHP Version 5.5.0-1ubuntu2~precise1
- nginx/1.4.1

### Edit

When I try to execute it from php-cli I get the same thing:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /blah/test.php on line 2`

Comment: Sure you're executing the same PHP version using the same php.ini in both cases?

Comment: I think php-fpm has it's own php.ini - perhaps try running from CLI? (pretty much what he said ^^)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same php.ini is being used in both cases. When I try to run it from the CLI I get the same thing `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /blah/test.php on line 2`

Comment: Looks like you were right. I checked my CLI and discovered the mongo driver wasn't being loaded there either. Added it to the CLI php.ini and it started working.

Comment: @deceze post as answer and take credit?

Comment: Please do. I'd love to give you guys credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your php.ini, you're probably using the wrong one. There are several for different ways to invoke PHP.

Comment: Thank you deceze and Paul for your help!