# How to build mongo.so or PHP with the correct module api version

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

Trying to install mongoDB on my MAMP setup. I have MAMP 3.05, which comes with PHP 5.5.10. Installed mongo using the instructions from the mongo [website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) and it seems to be running properly. Grabbed mongo extension from the mongo github [page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) and followed their instructions for building and adding the extension to php.ini.

Everything seems ok until I restart MAMP. In php_error.log, I see this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

It looks like the API number for php is a later version, so it would be nice not to have to rebuild an older version of PHP. Is there a way to rebuild the mongo extension with the correct module version, or do I have to discard MAMP and build PHP manually?

Comment: Are you loading the correct `mongo.so`? There does [not](http://serverfault.com/questions/563867/mongodb-unable-to-load-driver-on-php) seem [to be](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) a problem with [mongo extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492015/does-php-5-5-work-with-mongodb-driver) and PHP 5.5. Maybe take a closer look at the [installation steps in the PHP manual for OS X](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php).

Comment: @GhostGambler Thanks, but I tried the install using the PHP installation page you mention; it involves pecl. That wouldn't build at all because it couldn't find php.h. Instead I followed the instructions from the github page where I got the mongo source code. That builds mongo.so. I don't know how to tell it to build a different module version of mongo.so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with the command `which phpize` if you use the correct version of the `phpize` command. This should point to a directory similar to the one you installed your PHP5 into. Mine is found in `/usr/bin/phpize` which is the default OS X installation.

You can further run `phpize -v` to check the API version it links against. In my case (the default OS X PHP installation) it outputs:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

If the outputted API version does not match your required number `20121212` (in my case it is `20100412` which does not match) you are using the wrong `phpize` to configure the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this first

```
 sudo cp -r /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/S‌​DKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/php /usr/include/php
```